# Can't click action button on Snackbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-snackbar

Can't click the button on SnackBar inside fragment with data binding.

Here's java code:

```
        final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(binding.layoutMain, error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

    snackBar.setAction("TRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    snackBar.show();
```

[image]

Edit: 
Connection Error is not a dialog.

UPDATE:

I tried setting the NestedScrollView's visibility to GONE just to test. Snackbar seems to work properly. Is it something to do with the layout?

Comment: add some logic in your click listener than you know what happen

Comment: is the connection error a dialog?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729312/how-to-dismiss-a-snackbar-using-its-own-action-button) Implement a click action and let it empty . Clicking on empty click action will dismiss snackbar .

Comment: @KaranMer No its not

Comment: have you seen answer of this question it shows  snackBar.dismiss(); in onclicklistner

Comment: @MilanPansuriya tried that also. No luck. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @JhesterMag see my answer and you will get idea

Comment: have you written any code in onclick?

Comment: @KaranMer Yep. Same result.

Comment: try replacing your binded layout with any view object from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way to achieve action on snackbar

```
     final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(binding.layoutMain, error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do your code
  snackBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snackBar.show();
```

Comment: Still the same. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( coordinator_,
            service_name+" Service Added To Cart!", 1000);

    //setting the snackbar action button text size
    View view = snackbar.getView();
    TextView txt_action = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);
    TextView txt_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    txt_action.setTextSize(13);
    txt_action.setAllCaps(false);
    txt_text.setTextSize(13);
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.snackbar));

    snackbar.setAction("View Cart", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //your code
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(cb,"Your Text",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("COPY TO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

snackbar.show();
```

**and also try to  dismiss Dialog of no connection on click of snack bar**

Comment: Tried this. Still the same :( Thanks anyways.